# Is there a Mongo function for filtering all nested/subdocuments based on a field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have some documents in MongoDB that have other nested documents all with an "active" field.
For instance :

```
{
    "id": "PRODUCT1",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "active": true,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "CAT-1",
            "active": true,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "id": "SUBCAT-1",
                    "active": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "SUBCAT-2",
                    "active": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "CAT-2",
            "active": false,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "id": "SUBCAT-3",
                    "active": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to find all documents but only keep the "active" nested documents.

This is the result I'd like :

```
{
    "id": "PRODUCT1",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "active": true,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "CAT-1",
            "active": true,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "id": "SUBCAT-2",
                    "active": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Knowing that I do NOT know the document schema beforehand. That's why I need a sort of conditioned wildcard projection... (ie *.active=true). Is this possible or this HAS to be done serverside ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact).

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     { $redact: {
        $cond: {
           if: { $eq:["$active", true] },
           then: "$$DESCEND",
           else: "$$PRUNE"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
);
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/7UMphkH5OWn

Comment: This is such a neat way, totally forgot about `$redact`!

Answer (score 1):

```
//actual code out from mongo shell 4.2 on windows
//sample document as shared in problem statement, query to find the document from //collection
> db.products.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f748ee5377e73757bb7ceac"),
        "id" : "PRODUCT1",
        "name" : "Product 1",
        "active" : true,
        "categories" : [
                {
                        "id" : "CAT-1",
                        "active" : true,
                        "subcategories" : [
                                {
                                        "id" : "SUBCAT-1",
                                        "active" : false
                                },
                                {
                                        "id" : "SUBCAT-2",
                                        "active" : true
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "id" : "CAT-2",
                        "active" : false,
                        "subcategories" : [
                                {
                                        "id" : "SUBCAT-3",
                                        "active" : true
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
//verify mongo shell version no. for reference
> db.version();
4.2.6
//using aggregate and $unwind you can query the inner array elements as shown below
> db.products.aggregate([
... {$unwind: "$categories"},
... {$unwind: "$categories.subcategories"},
... {$match:{"active":true,
...          "categories.active":true,
...          "categories.subcategories.active":true}}
... ]).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f748ee5377e73757bb7ceac"),
        "id" : "PRODUCT1",
        "name" : "Product 1",
        "active" : true,
        "categories" : {
                "id" : "CAT-1",
                "active" : true,
                "subcategories" : {
                        "id" : "SUBCAT-2",
                        "active" : true
                }
        }
}
>
```

Comment: My issue is that the schema is not known beforehand. Not all documents have categories/subcategories, some have other subdocuments with "active", thus my question about achieving what you just did without explicitly specifying all the fields... I'm not sure this is even possible, but I'd like confirmation if not...

Comment: @SimoL. Please add sample JSON document for your above query. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to achieve this with a few `$map`, `$reduce` and `$filter` stages.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "categories": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$categories",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.active",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "categories": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$categories",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                "subcategories": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$this.subcategories",
                    "cond": {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.active",
                        true
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Executing the above will give you the following result based on your input

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "active": true,
    "categories": [
      {
        "active": true,
        "id": "CAT-1",
        "subcategories": [
          {
            "active": true,
            "id": "SUBCAT-2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "id": "PRODUCT1",
    "name": "Product 1"
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/fkkby-eibx2